# Petición GET con dos o más parámetros desde api fetch javascript (front-end) a api rest node (back-end)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, fetch, get

El siguiente código corresponde a una petición GET realizada desde el front-end usando la api fetch con javascript y la correspondiente recepción en en back-end mediante una api rest usando nodejs.
En este código, en la petición se adjunta un único parámetro (codgas.value). La necesidad es, poder adjuntar más de un parámetro. He intentado y buscado la sintaxis correspondiente sin éxito. ¿Alguien podría proporcionarla adjuntando dos parámetros? (Las líneas que cambian son las comentariadas con 1,2,3

Front-end (api fetch javascript):

```
fetch(url+codgas.value,{    //1
method: 'GET',
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
})
.then(response=>response.json())
.then(data=>{
let nuevoDato=[]
nuevoDato.push(data)
})
```

Back-end (api rest node):

```
app.get('/api/gasto/:codgas',(req,res)=>{   //2
    conexion.query('SELECT * FROM gasto WHERE codgas=?', [req.params.codgas],(error,fila)=>{ //3
        if(error){
            throw error
        } else {
            res.send(fila)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa [query string](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

```
fetch('https://example.com?' + new URLSearchParams({
    foo: 'value',
    bar: 2,
}))
```

Es muy importante el signo `?` al final de `url` como se ve arriba.

El resultado de `https://example.com?' + new URLSearchParams()` se verá así gracias a `toString()` que se esta invocando de manera implícita:

```
https://example.com?foo=value&bar=2
```

Podes obtener los `query string` en el `backend` de la siguiente manera:

```
app.get('/p', function(req, res) {
  let foo = req.query.foo; //'value'
  let bar = req.query.bar; //2
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @Nicolas Galarza. . Funcionó. Una sola observación. En mi caso, en el backend, let foo = req.query("foo") arrojaba el error: req.query no es una función. Sirvió: let foo = req.query.foo

Comment: @Rafael es verdad req.query no es una función, mi error, ya edito la respuesta y lo corrijo

Comment: Muchas gracias @Nicolás Galarza.